# MVC: what to pass in repository methods - entity or values?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have some repository methods which can update an whole entity or its parts (for example, when a user approves an invitation all i need to update is only "Approved" field). 
What is the best practice for passing parameters in such repo methods? Should i pass a whole entity "Invitation" and use only one field for updation or should i pass only entity's ID and the "Approved" value? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend passing the entity itself if you already have it. If you've already queried for it why make the repository query again?

The only time I pass an id around is in situations I don't already have the object, but that's pretty rare, as once I get the ID in the controller I tend to query for the object right there.

Comment: @Parrots, thanks for a quick reply. When user approves an invitation in the web browser i can create my domain object in the service layer having been got it by ID fro repo. Then i can set it approved and pass as a domain object back to repo where it will be re-converted to the linq2sql entity and updated in a DB. But don't you think it would be easier and lighter for the system just to pass ID and a value without any conversations from linq2sql to object model and back? In this case the repo method would retrieve an entity, set one field to a value and submit changes.

Comment: @Parrots, question #2, please. To implement an invitation approvement i also could use this way: to call a service-layer method "Approve" which retrieves an object, sets it approved and updates the whole entity with Update repo method. Is that better practice than to have a separate Approve repo method?

Comment: Re #1: I take advantage of EF's change tracking so all I work with within my domain layer are the objects themselves and I manipulate them as appropriate and that's it. I don't have update methods in my repo since EF does that for you for free with it's persistence tracking. Why should my domain care that it has to persist a change? Let EF do that for you and just worry about keeping domain logic (Domain.Approve(Entity entity) { entity.Approved = true; }) there. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/10/poco-in-the-entity-framework-part-3-change-tracking-with-poco.aspx

Comment: Re #2: If you use the persistence tracking in EF then it knows what fields are dirty, and will only update those that need it.

Comment: never tried wih EF - maybe it is really better thing. Ok, thank you.

Comment: General: I'm pretty sure doing things directly with SQL (passing IDs, etc) would always be faster (to some degree), but I feel like it keeps the code a lot nicer letting EF do the persistence and working with domain objects everywhere. Makes it so my domain doesn't have persistence logic.